# response to professional apology

Tags: email

Wanted to respond to a professional email where the supervisor said they're sorry they won't be at work due to being out of town. can't find a good response, any tips?

Answer (score 1):

The email 'apology' is a matter of form, as should be the response. The most routine of replies will suffice, e.g. "Thank you for letting me know", if, that is, any response is needed.